# Save the data from a solver output to a list in Python

Tags: python

In python when you run a solver, it displays some details along with the solutions.

For example, I used a solver called IPOPT using following code

```
solver = SolverFactory('ipopt')
solver.solve(model, tee=True)
```

and, I got the following output from a solver:

```
This is Ipopt version 3.11.1, running with linear solver mumps.

Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:        6
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:        0
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:        3

Total number of variables............................:        4
                     variables with only lower bounds:        2
                variables with lower and upper bounds:        2
                     variables with only upper bounds:        0
Total number of equality constraints.................:        2
Total number of inequality constraints...............:        0


iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
   0 2.0402000e+000 1.35e-002 1.00e+000  -1.0 0.00e+000    -  0.00e+000 0.00e+000   0
   1 2.2708093e+000 1.01e-001 1.38e-001  -1.0 1.72e+000    -  1.00e+000 1.00e+000f  1
   2 2.1698603e+000 2.96e-002 3.73e-002  -1.0 2.85e+000    -  1.00e+000 1.00e+000h  1
   3 2.0024980e+000 2.74e-001 4.00e-002  -2.5 4.47e+000    -  9.79e-001 9.85e-001h  1
   4 2.0056830e+000 1.35e-004 1.30e-004  -2.5 1.66e-001    -  1.00e+000 1.00e+000h  1
   5 2.0002989e+000 3.63e-006 3.17e-005  -3.8 2.68e-003    -  1.00e+000 1.00e+000h  1
   6 2.0000036e+000 1.09e-008 1.18e-007  -5.7 1.47e-004    -  1.00e+000 1.00e+000h  1
   7 2.0000000e+000 1.69e-012 1.73e-011  -8.6 1.84e-006    -  1.00e+000 1.00e+000h  1
```

And now from the display, I want to save some information, for example, columns from the above table into a list. For instance, from the table, I want two lists from columns "iter" and "objective".

So, is it possible to save those information? Can someone help me to do it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You need to capture the output to stdout, and then process it. These are two different questions. We don't know what your library supports in terms of capture. You could process using csv breaking on whitespace, or perhaps use pandas. There are lots of options and unknowns. Split up the task, and search/ask a more specific question. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].